# Web application not accessible using server name or IP address

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I have a web application published on our Windows Server 2008 R2 (running IIS7). I can access it through 
http://localhost/WebApp without any problem.

However, if I try using http://servername/WebApp or http://IP_address/WebApp (from both server machine itself or from a client machine) then it won't show the page correctly (Access Denied Message while login my apps).

My application is developed in ASP.NET and and uses Crystal Reports 2008.

Permissions: Authenticated user and Iuser (folders).

Authentication: Anonymous and Forms are enabled

Please help me to access my application by both IP address and server name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple answer is that you need to configure IIS Host file for your server. This is located here: C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

You can add another line similar to the one above, and give it the server name.